# Adding static library file to the makefile

Tags: gcc, makefile, arm, gnu-make, stm32

I have following makefile executed by python script:

```
SOURCES_DIRECTORY = sources

# These directories should be created by build.py script
BUILD_DIRECTORY = builds
OBJECTS_DIRECTORY = objs

CORE = cortex-m4

LINKER_SCRIPT = linker_rom.ld

# C definitions
ifeq ($(RAM_FLASH), 1) 
    C_DEFS = -DRAM_FLASH
else
    C_DEFS =
endif

INC_DIRS = sources
SRCS_DIRS = sources

# extension of C files
C_EXT = c

# wildcard for C source files (all files with C_EXT extension found in current
# folder and SRCS_DIRS folders will be compiled and linked)
C_SRCS = $(wildcard $(patsubst %, %/*.$(C_EXT), . $(SRCS_DIRS)))

# extension of ASM files
AS_EXT = s

# wildcard for ASM source files (all files with AS_EXT extension found in
# current folder and SRCS_DIRS folders will be compiled and linked)
AS_SRCS = $(wildcard $(patsubst %, %/*.$(AS_EXT), . $(SRCS_DIRS)))

# optimization flags ("-O0" - no optimization, "-O1" - optimize, "-O2" -
# optimize even more, "-Os" - optimize for size or "-O3" - optimize yet more) 
OPTIMIZATION = -Og

# set to 1 to optimize size by removing unused code and data during link phase
REMOVE_UNUSED = 1

C_WARNINGS = -Wall -Wextra -Werror

# C language standard ("c89" / "iso9899:1990", "iso9899:199409",
# "c99" / "iso9899:1999", "gnu89" - default, "gnu99")
C_STD = c99

VPATH = $(SRCS_DIRS)

#============================================#
#           Toolchain Configuration          #
#============================================#
TOOLCHAIN = arm-none-eabi-

CXX = $(TOOLCHAIN)g++
CC = $(TOOLCHAIN)gcc
AS = $(TOOLCHAIN)gcc -x assembler-with-cpp
OBJCOPY = $(TOOLCHAIN)objcopy
OBJDUMP = $(TOOLCHAIN)objdump
SIZE = $(TOOLCHAIN)size
RM = rm -f

.PHONY: all clean

#=============================================================================#
# various compilation flags
#=============================================================================#

# core flags
CORE_FLAGS = -mcpu=$(CORE) -mthumb -specs=nano.specs -specs=nosys.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard

# flags for C compiler
C_FLAGS = -std=$(C_STD) -g -ggdb3 -fverbose-asm -Wa,-ahlms=$(OBJECTS_DIRECTORY)/$(notdir $(<:.$(C_EXT)=.lst)) -DSTM32F429xx $(FLAGS) 

# flags for assembler
AS_FLAGS = -g -ggdb3 -Wa,-amhls=$(OBJECTS_DIRECTORY)/$(notdir $(<:.$(AS_EXT)=.lst)) $(FLAGS)

# flags for linker
LD_FLAGS = -T$(LINKER_SCRIPT) -g -Wl,-Map=$(OBJECTS_DIRECTORY)/test.map,--cref,--no-warn-mismatch

# process option for removing unused code
ifeq ($(REMOVE_UNUSED), 1)
    LD_FLAGS += -Wl,--gc-sections
    OPTIMIZATION += -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections
endif

LIBS = libmylib.a
LIB_DIRS = ./sources

#=============================================================================#
# do some formatting
#=============================================================================#

C_OBJS = $(addprefix $(OBJECTS_DIRECTORY)/, $(notdir $(C_SRCS:.$(C_EXT)=.o)))
AS_OBJS = $(addprefix $(OBJECTS_DIRECTORY)/, $(notdir $(AS_SRCS:.$(AS_EXT)=.o)))
OBJS = $(AS_OBJS) $(C_OBJS) $(CXX_OBJS) $(USER_OBJS)
DEPS = $(OBJS:.o=.d)
INC_DIRS_F = -I. $(patsubst %, -I%, $(INC_DIRS))
LIB_DIRS_F = $(patsubst %, -L%, $(LIB_DIRS))

ELF = $(BUILD_DIRECTORY)/$(NAME).elf
HEX = $(BUILD_DIRECTORY)/$(NAME).hex
BIN = $(BUILD_DIRECTORY)/$(NAME).bin
LSS = $(BUILD_DIRECTORY)/$(NAME).lss
DMP = $(BUILD_DIRECTORY)/$(NAME).dmp

# format final flags for tools, request dependancies for C++, C and asm
C_FLAGS_F = $(CORE_FLAGS) $(OPTIMIZATION) $(C_WARNINGS) $(C_FLAGS) $(C_DEFS) -MD -MP -MF $(OBJECTS_DIRECTORY)/$(@F:.o=.d) $(INC_DIRS_F)
AS_FLAGS_F = $(CORE_FLAGS) $(AS_FLAGS) $(AS_DEFS) -MD -MP -MF $(OBJECTS_DIRECTORY)/$(@F:.o=.d) $(INC_DIRS_F)
LD_FLAGS_F = $(CORE_FLAGS) $(LD_FLAGS) $(LIB_DIRS_F)

#contents of output directory
GENERATED = $(wildcard $(patsubst %, $(BUILD_DIRECTORY)/*.%, bin d dmp elf hex lss lst map o))


#=============================================================================#
# make all
#=============================================================================#

all : $(ELF) $(LSS) $(DMP) $(HEX) $(BIN)

# make object files dependent on Makefile
$(OBJS) : $(MAKEFILE_NAME)
# make .elf file dependent on linker script
$(ELF) : $(LINKER_SCRIPT)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# linking - objects -> elf
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#

$(ELF) : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LD_FLAGS_F) $(OBJS) $(LIBS) -o $@

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# compiling - C source -> objects
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#

objs/%.o : %.$(C_EXT)
    $(CC) -c $(C_FLAGS_F) $< -o $@

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# assembling - ASM source -> objects
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#

objs/%.o : %.$(AS_EXT)
    $(AS) -c $(AS_FLAGS_F) $< -o $@

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# memory images - elf -> hex, elf -> bin
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#

$(HEX) : $(ELF)
    $(OBJCOPY) -O ihex $< $@

$(BIN) : $(ELF)
    $(OBJCOPY) -O binary $< $@

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# memory dump - elf -> dmp
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#

$(DMP) : $(ELF)
    $(OBJDUMP) -x --syms $< > $@

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# extended listing - elf -> lss
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#

$(LSS) : $(ELF)
    $(OBJDUMP) -S $< > $@

# include dependancy files
-include $(DEPS)
```

This is the project tree

-> /sources/

-> /sources/libmylib.a

-> /makefile

I thought adding

```
LIBS = libmylib.a
LIB_DIRS = ./sources
```

will solve the problem. My lib is libmylib.a file. However console still outputs the errors with undefined references to functions. What should I change?
Path to the directories with sources, objects, headers and flags are passed dynamically by the python script as arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

`LIBS = -lmylib`

The compiler will prepend  `lib` and append `.a` to the libraries you specify, making it look for a library file named `libmylib.a` which is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jacek. Still not working, but I'm sure you're right about this. Don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Is it possible to print some params which are provided to makefile so I will be able to check paths etc. ?

Comment: Passing `-v` will cause it to print additional information, including library search paths. Add it to the `LD_FLAGS`.